# What are the effects of Education by people of Foreign Cultures?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So, I think at this point, I have established the following:

- Educating your heir with a foreign culture can really harm your
  vassals opinion of you. (And, subsequently, their opinion of him when
  he grows up to be that culture.)
- *Sometimes* getting a child of one culture educated by an adult of another can result in that child coming out as the adult's culture.
  This will result in a warning (eg. "Princess Ewewuijhsjkhdsjk might
  become English!") and then has a chance of happening, based on mean
  times to happen. ([As discussed here](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Education))

So, what I'm beginning to suspect, which is based on something mentioned near the end of that page, is that there are some circumstances in which a foreign guardian will not push their culture on the child. This is also based on the fact that sometimes I don't get warnings saying the child will change cultures, even though they otherwise would.

So my questions are these:

- Can we confirm, like the article says, that if the liege of the
  guardian is not of a foreign culture, that the child will not become
  a foreign culture?
- Does this work the other way around? (Does it become the case that the liege's culture is dominant, and that sending a child of a culture, to a guardian of a culture, with a liege of some other culture result in gaining that lieges culture?)
- Does your culture play a role in this at all?
- Are there still negative effects when your heir is educated by a different culture, but is not in danger of becoming that culture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is event 38110 in `guardian_events.txt`, triggered on the child

```
guardian = {
    NOT = { culture = ROOT }
    location = { culture = PREV }
    employer = {
        culture = PREV
    }
}
```

So a child can only convert if

- Child is not the culture of the guardian
- <strike>Guardian's location (province) is the same culture as the guardian</strike>
- Guardian's employer is the same culture as the guardian. If guardian is landowner, he counts as his own employer.
  Although without things going nutty, you can't pick courtiers of another landowner to educate a child, so I think this is more to prevent your courtiers from converting your children's culture if your capital is in different culture land for whatever reason (aka recently conquered 7 slot provinces)

That should cover your first three questions. I don't believe there any any other negative effects.

EDIT - This seems to differ across patches. Currently (2.1.6) it is

```
guardian = {
    NOT = { culture = ROOT }
    employer = {
        culture = PREV
    }
}
```

So scratch the province location restriction.